# Read for-each-loop container variable in OLEDB source variable windows

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I make one table named QueryTable that store 4 SQL queries each have different meta data

[image]

I want to store these four queries result in Excel sheet

First I have taken executable SQL task and configured the connection and Result Set as a Full Result Set, Query statement.

[image]

After that open Result Set tab and create Query_variable as a object type.

[image]

2) Drag the For-Each_loop container and set Foreach ADO Enumerator in collection part and assign Query_variable

[image]

In variable mapping part create new variable as string type to store four queries. Result.

[image]

3) Finally add I one data flow task add OLEDB source configure with Same variable (That I have given in for each loop container).

Rightnow it is showing default value what i have given in User::Variable

[image]

I can iterate same No of column (Meta-data) queries and store in excel destination

[image]

But the Problem is  when variable goes to next query that holds lesser or greater no of column.Here package fail cant handle different meta data table

[image]

Please assist me ,Can we iterate different meta data queries same time with proper output?

**I Hope I have Explain the Problem what i facing exactly**

Comment: Please help somone...I am eagerly waiting couple of hours....Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

Set the default value of `User::Variable` to one of the queries, so that BIDS can validate it at design time.

You can also try setting "DelayValidation" to true, but that might not be enough in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Tab Alleman!!...I can iterate same no of column queries smoothly but when any queries comes in variable part that have greater and lesser number of column ....Here package fail..Can  we iterate this?

Comment: No, you can only iterate queries that have the exact same columns.   Any queries with different columns have to have their own dataflow.

Comment: Is there any other approach to achive desired result...that mean store different meta data queries result only one Excel sheet tab as per client requirement?

Comment: You could probably write a script task that could do it.   I can't think of any other approach that would let you iterate queries with different meta-data.

Answer (score 1):

Set the delay validation to true for both the data flow and the for each loop container.

Comment: :Sorry for mention this...Already set Delay Validation->True for same ..Still Showing same error

Comment: Have you tried using 4 different sql task for creating 4 worksheets in your file?

Comment: Yes ,i already had done that works fine but can not store all data flow task result in only one Excel sheet tab ...there was overwritten problem occur...client want all these queries with different number of columns  results in only one excel sheet tab not any other excel tab ....here is the problem...... Is there any other approach to achieve result?please respond I am waiting for approach.....

Comment: you are trying to get 4 different worksheets in a single excel file but with each worksheet having different columns right?

Comment: Sorry @Minhal.. client want only single worksheet excel that hold all four 4 queries result

Comment: @Ankush It's not possible to have 4 different queries result with different columns for each queries in a single worksheet.

Comment: It can only be done by creating multiple worksheets for each query for a single file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199327/discussion-between-ankush-and-minhal).